# Create Index on partial CHAR Column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-tuning

I have a CHAR(250) column being used as a foreign key to a varchar(24) column.

In MySQL I recall that I could create an index specifying column(24) in order to create an index on the leftmost 24 characters.  This doesn't appear to be possible on MS SQL Server.

My question is this:

Is it possible to use an indexed view on SQL Server 2008 to index a substring of that column, and if so, would it have any side-effects on the table's performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a persisted computed column, then index it, see [Creating Indexes on Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

```
alter table add newcolumn as cast(oldcolumn as varchar(24)) persisted;
create index table_newcolumn on table (newcolumn);
```

Comment: Thanks!  What I neglected to mention though is that the table in question is part of a 3rd party app, so changing the table itself is strictly verboten.

Comment: I'm not sure though that the FK will benefit from the indexed view. Queries and joins *may* benefit from it, but the FK enforcements itself might ignore your indexed view resulting in poor performance for the FK enforcement validations.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I'll just have to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have a good *relational* reason for doing this.  I'm guessing the first 24 characters of the vendor-provided table actually constitute a discrete attribute and should have been in a separate column in the first place.

So...

Create a view of the vendor's table.  Index it if you like.  I doubt you can point a FK constraint at the view, but you certainly can write a trigger to the same effect.  A trigger checking against an indexed view will be very fast, at the cost of a slight increase in update times on the view's base table.

HTH.

Comment: There is no goo relational reason, it's a decision which was made before my time I'm more or less stuck with.  There is no *actual* FK constraint to worry about.  It's already in an entirely separate database on the same server.  I have a stored procedure which takes 40 minutes to run I'm mainly concerned with.  Putting an index on that field just seemed excessively large (~400mb).  Disk space isn't really that much of a concern though, so if there aren't any other performance benefits to speak of, I'm just wasting my time.