# Specifying the number of chars to be included in a compound index in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am reusing portions of a PostgreSQL schema in a SSQL database.

This is a snippet of my SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE pac_region 
(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 country_id INTEGER REFERENCES Country(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
 name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_pac_region_name ON pac_region(country_id, name(32));
```

I want to specify that only the first 32 chars of the name need to be unique (when combined with the country_id).

SSMS barfs at the `(32)` specification. What is the correct way to restrict the length of a text used in a compound index, in TSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can create a index partially on a column, like what you are trying. 
Rather, you can create a `persisted computed column` and add index on that column like

Taken from [Create Index on partial CHAR Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028868/create-index-on-partial-char-column)

```
alter table pac_region 
add Computed_Name as cast(name as varchar(32)) persisted;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_pac_region_name 
ON pac_region(country_id, Computed_Name);
```

(OR)

Probably by creating a indexed view.

Comment: Does this actually store only the first 32 characters in the index's BTree, or is the whole `name` stored and truncated on-the-fly at run time?

Comment: @MichaelGreen, you are actually creating index on a new column which is 32 char long (which is also kind of substring value of the original column value)